# Package 'SassAndCoffee.Core 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have made .net core 2.0 web app. I have added SassAndCoffee.Core -v 1 or current version using NUGET and then I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning NU1701  Package 'SassAndCoffee.Core 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like author did not update [the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SassAndCoffee.Core/) since 5/16/2013. The latest package `2.1.1` is not compatible with .NET Core.

However, if you do not plan to host in cross platform such as Linux, then you can still create ASP.NET Core Web App using Full .NET Framework. Then, you can reference `SassAndCoffee.Core`.

Otherwise, you'll have to contact author or fork it from [github](https://github.com/paulcbetts/SassAndCoffee) and make it compatible with `.NET Standard`.

[image]